# Can we deploy spring application on tomcat 7?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Can we deploy spring application on tomcat 7? I have built an application on spring boot but someone said that it is not compatible with tomcat 7. Now I plan to migrate it to spring, will that be compatible with tomcat7? Please confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on Spring Boot version, i.e. the required Servlet specification version.

See [Apache Tomcat Versions](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) for table of Tomcat ↔ Servlet versions.

- [**1.5.18.RELEASE**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.18.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_servlet_containers) - Any Servlet 3.0+ compatible container, i.e. Tomcat 7+
  *Official:* Tomcat 7, Tomcat 8
- [**2.0.0.RELEASE**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-system-requirements-servlet-containers) - Any Servlet 3.0+ compatible container, i.e. Tomcat 7+
  *Official:* Tomcat 8.5
- [**2.1.0.RELEASE**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-system-requirements-servlet-containers) - Any Servlet 3.1+ compatible container, i.e. Tomcat 8+
  *Official:* Tomcat 9.0

Comment: Can we convwrt spring boot 2 application to spring boot 1.5? If yes then how? I am relatively new to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RAHULKOHLI No need. As you can see, Boot 2.0 should support Tomcat 7.

Comment: But i get errors. Coule you also help me with the JDK version with which I should build this. I need to use atleast JDK7 as a part of my code doesn't support 6. Will a combination of JDK7 and spring boot 2+ work. I'll be grateful to you if you also confirm the steps to downgrade to exactly springboot 2.0  as I am using Springboot 2+ version

Comment: @RAHULKOHLI If you scroll one page back in each link, you'll see that Boot 2.0 and 2.1 requires Java 8, and Boot 1.5.18 requires Java 7. Since Java 7 is End of Free Public Updates since April 2015, you should run with Java 8, even if you use Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Maybe it depends on which version that you are using.
You can check https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy